# How does Warframe experience work?

Tags: warframe

The page [Experience Mechanics](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_Mechanics) on the Warframe Wikia says

> [...]If the enemy was killed by an ability, your Warframe will gain all the experience.

I've noticed though it not seems valid anymore. I was in a Defence Mission with my Nekros, and everytime I used Desecrate, the affinity bar of my rifle (or any other weapon I had equipped) started blinking, like everytime I kill an enemy with that weapon.

After that I tried with my Nova. I spammed Molecular Prime to ensure to get as most kills as possible. I resulted in more experience at the end of the game, not only on my Warframe, but also on my weapons.

The next game instead, I completely leeched the game, no kills at all. Based on the same article on the wiki, I should have get 100% on the exp divided by all the equip I had. Since I were full equipped, I should have get 25% exp on every equip I had. At the end of the game though, I got less experience in all equip that the round before, where I killed most of the enemies.

It seems to me that now every kill you do with your Warframe, grants you exp to everything you have equipped, and the "leech method" where you should get all the experience evenly distributed doesn't work anymore.

So the question is: who is wrong? me or the wiki? I've red on reddit people talking about the same thing the wiki does. Does the UPDATE 14 changed something? Are there more complete details on how experience is given to players?

All the test were made in Eris-Xini wave 1 to 10.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Sorry I will try to complete my question with... a question. Anyway I'm asking who is wrong between me and the wiki.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a theory than an answer, too long for comments.

The wiki article is most likely out of date.
Some time in U12 (12.6?) affinity orbs and mission affinity rewards were changed to split affinity equally between equipped gear instead of **100% to equipped warframe**

This mechanic could unintentionally(introduced as a bug?) affect Warframe kills which also granted 100% to Warframe. Confirming will require further testing.

Comment: So it seems that no one really knows how experience works now. I will test more and I will take note of all the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me if I'm off topic of your question but this is how I can think to answer your oddly phrased question.

***According to the wiki:***

Killing an enemy with a warframe ability (molecular prime) will grant 100% of the experience from each enemy killed to your warframe. If you use weapons, it splits the experience 50/50 between your warframe and weapon.

When you're playing co-op and an ally kills an enemy, the experience gained is equally divided between your frame and each weapon.

***According to personal experience:***

When I first started playing warframe I had my friend explain the experience mechanics to me. He was probably completely wrong **but** it actually does make sense. He's told me that when you kill an enemy with an ability/weapon, you get 100% of the total experience toward your correlating weapon/frame, and then it divides the experience between your other gear. This CAN NOT be 100% correct (since I've never actually levelled a secondary by using my primaries) but I don't think hes too far off of the actual answer.

In all this leads me to believe that, when you kill an enemy with an ability, it gives you 100% of that total experience to your frame and then an additional bonus to your weapons. In regards to your "leeching method", its an inaccurate test according to this:
`Kills: You get a bonus 50% experience from all kills at the end of mission.`
If you want an accurate comparison, multiply your experience from the kill run by 2/3 (100% + 50% = 150% total, 2/3 of this would be 100%).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the experience you get when you kill with weapons will be split 50/50 between Warframes and weapons. However, when you kill enemies with your Warframe abilities, 75% of the affinity goes to your Warframe, while 25% gets divided between your weapons.

The most efficient way to get XP is to "leech", i.e to get the XP from the kills of a squadmate, because the XP gets divided 25% to your Warframe and 75% divided among your weapons.